# enable_shared_from_this and inheritance

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I've got a type which inherits from `enable_shared_from_this<type>`, and another type that inherits from this type. Now I can't use the shared_from_this method because it returns the base type and in a specific derived class method I need the derived type. Is it valid to just construct a shared_ptr from this directly?

Edit:
In a related question, how can I move from an rvalue of type `shared_ptr<base>` to a type of `shared_ptr<derived>`? I used dynamic_cast to verify that it really was the correct type, but now I can't seem to accomplish the actual move.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Once you obtain the `shared_ptr<Base>`, you can use [`static_pointer_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#static_pointer_cast) to convert it to a `shared_ptr<Derived>`.

You can't just create a `shared_ptr` directly from `this`; that would be equivalent to:

```
shared_ptr<T> x(new T());
shared_ptr<T> y(x.get()); // now you have two separate reference counts
```

Comment: No, you can't downcast `shared_ptr<Base>` to `shared_ptr<Derived>` with `static_pointer_cast`. One has to use `dynamic_pointer_cast` as there may be any number of derived classes.

Comment: @Myon Why not? What do you mean?

Comment: @curiousguy: You can use `static_pointer_cast` if you're using non-virtual inheritance and you're 100% sure of the type you are casting to. Any other case is undefined behavior. So in general use `dynamic_pointer_cast` and you'll be on the safe side - that's what I ment.