# Unable to compile with inheritance of shared_from_this

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, shared-ptr

I'm using an home made shared_from_this class (CEnableSharedFromThis) because I'm under C++03 and I can't use boost on my project.

I have a class A which look like this :

```
class A : virtual CEnableSharedFromThis<A>
{
...
}
```

and class B like that :

```
class B : public A, virtual CEnableSharedFromThis<A>
{
   void foo()
   {
      Poco::SharedPtr<B> b(sharedFromthis());
   }
}
```

I see some people that have an error with an ambigous method. So I use virtual inheritance and I don't have this error.

But I have a new one that I can't give up in the foo() method.

The compiler says :

> error: cannot convert from base `CEnableSharedFromThis<A>` to derived
>   type `A` via virtual base `CEnableSharedFromThis<A>`

So I try the following foo() method :

```
   void foo()
   {
      Poco::SharedPtr<B> b(B::sharedFromthis());
   }
```

But it changes nothing.

Any idea ?

EDIT :

Following your recommandations I remove the inheritance of CEnableSharedFromThis of B and change foo() function like that :

```
class B : public A
{
   void foo()
   {
      Poco::SharedPtr<B> b(sharedFromthis().cast<B>());
   }
}
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `class B : public A, virtual CEnableSharedFromThis<B>`?

Comment: @m.s. but what would the virtual inheritance do, then? They're completely different classes, no?

Comment: the virtual inheritance should not be necessary at all (neither for `A` nor for `B`). Only `A` should inherit from `CEnableSharedFromThis`  (see [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4491420/enable-shared-from-this-and-inheritance)); virtual inheritance would be necessary if you have multiple inheritance (see [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16082785/use-of-enable-shared-from-this-with-multiple-inheritance))

Comment: In my case, The caller must get an instance of B and not A. so If I remove the inheritance from CEnableSharedFromThis of B I only get a shardePtr of A and not B

Comment: You can use static_pointer_cast to cast up the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Override it and use static_pointer_cast instead.

```
class B : public A
{
   Poco::SharedPtr<B> sharedFromThis() {
       return Poco::StaticPointerCast<B>(CEnableSharedFromThis<A>::sharedFromThis());
   }
   void foo()
   {
      Poco::SharedPtr<B> b(sharedFromthis());
   }
}
```

This is assuming the existence of an analogous `Poco::StaticPointerCast` to `std::static_pointer_cast`.